# How many temporary std::string object be created in the code? (Effective Modern C++ materials)

Tags: c++, c++14, stdstring

I have been studying Effective Modern C++11 and 14 recently.

I went through a part of the book located on page 171, item 25, where the author provides two code examples for the setName function.

(1)

```
// Option 1, universal reference
class Widget {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void setName(T &&newName)     // universal reference
    { name = std::move(newName); }// compiles, but is // bad, bad, bad!
                                  //…
private:
    std::string name;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeDataStructure> p;
};

void main() {
    Widget w;
    w.setName("Adela Novak");
}
```

(2)

```
// Option 2, lvalue reference and rvalue reference
class Widget2 {
public:
    void setName(const std::string &newName) { name = newName; }
    void setName(std::string &&newName) { name = std::move(newName); }
    //…
};

void main() {
    Widget2 w;
    w.setName("Adela Novak");
}
```

The author said:

> With the version of setName taking a universal reference, the string
> literal "Adela Novak" would be passed to setName, where it would be
> conveyed to the assignment operator for the std::string inside w. w’s
> name data member would thus be assigned directly from the string
> literal; no temporary std::string objects would arise.
>
> With the overloaded versions of setName, however, a temporary
> std::string object would be created for setName’s parameter to bind
> to, and this temporary std::string would then be moved into w’s data
> member. A call to setName would thus entail execution of one
> std::string constructor (to create the temporary), one std::string
> move assignment operator (to move newName into w.name), and one
> std::string destructor (to destroy the temporary).

If my understanding is correct, in both option 1 and option 2, we will create a temporary std::string object for “Adela Novak” implicitly in main() function.

For option 1, we send that temporary std::string object to setName(), and then T&& will be deduced as rvalue because “Adela Novak” is rvalue.

Hence, in option 1, we only create one temporary std::string object.

For option 2, we send that temporary std::string object to setName(). Because “Adela Novak” is rvalue, so we will pick up the rvalue overload setName() function. But, when we are going to call rvalue overload function, we have to create another temporary std::string object explicitly for newName.

Hence, in option 2, we have to create two temporary std::string objects.

My question is:

1. Why don’t we have to create another temporary std::string object for newName in option 1?
2. Why we have to create another temporary std::string object for newName in option 2?
3. How to know that the member function we are going to call will create a temporary object or not?

Updated:
I asked my question to ChatGPT. However, it seems like the answer ChatGPT provided not 100% author's answer...

> In Option 1, when the string literal "Adela Novak" is passed to the setName() function, the type deduction of T results in T being deduced as a const char* pointer. Since T is a non-reference type, newName is declared as an rvalue reference (`T&&`).
>
> When the rvalue reference `newName` is passed to the `std::move()` function, it performs a cast to an rvalue, which allows it to bind to the move constructor of the `std::string` class. Therefore, a temporary `std::string` object is created using the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*` argument.
>
> This temporary `std::string` object is then moved to the `name` data member using the move assignment operator, resulting in no further copies of the string data.
>
> So, in Option 1, one temporary `std::string` object is created to hold the string data, but no additional temporary objects are created.

> In Option 2, when the string literal "Adela Novak" is passed to the `setName()` function, the compiler tries to find the best match for the argument.
>
> The first `setName()` function taking a `const std::string&` parameter is a match because it can bind to a temporary `std::string` object created from the string literal. Therefore, the temporary `std::string` object is created using the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*` argument.
>
> Next, the temporary `std::string` object is passed to the `setName()` function by reference, which triggers the copy constructor of `std::string` to create a copy of the temporary object.
>
> Finally, the temporary `std::string` object is moved to the `name` data member using the move assignment operator, which results in the temporary object being destroyed.
>
> So, in Option 2, two temporary `std::string` objects are created, one for holding the string data, and another one for binding to the `std::string&&` parameter of the overloaded `setName()` function.

Comment: `“Adela Novak”` is not an rvalue.  All string literals are lvalues.

Comment: Further, `"Adela Novak"` is a char array, not `std::string`. Where would a temporary `std::string` come from?

Comment: All those `setName()` are not optimal: 1 `name` is default initialized and then assigned in the constructor; 2. Overloaded `setName()` is not needed. I would make it `void setName(std::string newName): name(std::move(newName) {}`. It covers `const std::string &newName`, just creates a string copy earlier. It also covers `std::string &&newName`.

Comment: 3. You have to create a temporary when the argument doesn't match the parameter type. Here `"Adela Novak"`  isn't a `std::string`, so one has to be created. Now, the cost of creating a 10-15 character std::string is essentially zero, so I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I'm kind of more confused now. "Adela Novak" is const char array* pointer, and it is a lvalue. Hence, in option 1, T will be deduced to const char array* pointer, right? And we can use std::move() to transfer the data of string literals to std::string name w/o creating any temporary std::string object as well?

Comment: How about in option 2, because "Adela Novak" is lvalue. Hence, we are going to call lvalue overload function right? When we call that lvalue overload function, the extra cost is we have to create a std::string object newName, am I correct?

Comment: The std::move() is a red herring here, it does nothing for string literals. But there is an assignment operator that takes `const char*`.

Comment: Also, side-note here, but surely the first example should be using `name = std::forward<T>(newName);`, not `name = std::move(newName);`? `newName` could be a `const` l-value, right? `std::forward<T>` would handle that (forwarding as `const` l-value), while `std::move` would try to convert it to an r-value, which makes no sense.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes you are correct, author did mention `name = std::forward<T>(newName);` is the correct way to implement

Comment: In example 1, what happens when `setName(3.14159)` is called?  You are either assuming that every type can be assigned to a string or you are requiring the existence of a "to string" assignment operator for every type `T`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `std::move` in that case would still cast to a const l-value. The problem would be if newName is *not* const, which would (most likely unintentionally) modify what `newName` is a reference of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author is clear about option 1:

> [..] the **string literal** "Adela Novak" would be passed to setName, where it would be conveyed to the assignment operator for the std::string inside w. w’s name data member would thus be assigned directly from the string literal; **no temporary std::string objects would arise**.

A string literal is not an `std::string`, it's a char array (`const char[]`). So the universal reference allows you to pass an object of *any type* without any conversion or temporary objects.

As for option 2, a temporary object may or may not be created, depends on what you pass in `setName`. If you pass an `std::string`, then no temporaries will be created. If you pass a string literal, you need a temporary `std::string` to be created first and then pass a reference to it.

```cpp
void foo(const std::string& s) { ... }
void foo(std::string&& s) { ... }

int main() {
    std::string str(10, 'a'); // "aaaaaaaaaa"
    foo(str); // No temporary, passing a reference to 'str'
    foo("Hello"); // Creating a temporary std::string and passing a reference to the temporary
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks for your explanation!! It's all because the flexibility that universal reference provide! That allows us to pass an object of any type without any conversion or temporary objects. But, in lvalue overload or rvalue overload, we have to provide an argument that match lvalue reference type or rvalue reference type

Comment: One more follow up question. In option 1, `name=std::move(newName)`, we will not create another temporary std::string object as well? Because std::string support us use std::move with string literal directly?

Comment: std::move is nothing but a simple cast to r-value reference, which in turn triggers the r-value ref overload of the assignment operator.

Comment: I knew that definition, I think I overthink too much and making thing complicated now. By the way, in option 2, what overload function are we going to call? My thought is lvalue one, am I correct?

Comment: It's going to be the r-value one, as is the case with any temporary object. https://godbolt.org/z/rq3KhsaTd

Comment: You are correct, I mixed up again. Because we create the temporary std::string object for that string literal. Temporary std::string object should be r-value, because it is not a variable.